# Awesomium WebControl does not load Activex

Tags: asp.net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, awesomium

I am using awesomium webcontrol in my WPF application and it works fine but it does not load any ActiveX plugin. Here is code i am using:

```
<my:WebControl x:Name="wcPlayback" Width="960" Height="710"></my:WebControl>

wcPlayback.Source =
            new Uri(
                @"http://(Domain)/main.aspx?ip=158.52.142.104&port=884&u=12345&p=12345");
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX is a Microsoft technology and only runs in Internet Explorer. Awesomium uses a Chrome browser.